# Insert with PHP associative array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I'm facing a little problem and I don't know is it's possible to achieve it or not. Let me explain :

I have an associative array like this :

```
Array
(
    [res_id] => 104
    [subject] => Test
    [type_id] => 503
    [format] => pdf
    [typist] => fefe
    [creation_date] => 2017-02-10 14:27:37.236711
    [modification_date] => 2017-02-10 14:27:37.236711
    [fulltext_result] => 1
    [doc_date] => 2017-02-01 00:00:00
    [docserver_id] => FASTHD_MAN
    [path] => 2017#02#0001##
    [filename] => 0008.pdf
    [fingerprint] => 
    [filesize] => 84979
    [status] => VAL
    [destination] => DSG
    [priority] => 2
    [is_multi_docservers] => N
    [is_frozen] => N
    [tablename] => res_letterbox
    [initiator] => COU
    [dest_user] => ddaull
    [locker_user_id] => fefefef
    [locker_time] => 2017-02-13 15:52:25.624521
    [confidentiality] => N
    [tnl_path] => 2017#02#0001##
    [tnl_filename] => 0008.png
)
```

I want to know if I can use this associative array, in order to make an INSERT TO request ? I want the first part of the array (like res_id, subject) goes to column part for the insertion. The second part of the array (like 104,Test) will go to the values

Thanks in advance for your help, hope I am clear enough..

Comment: Sure it's possible, but you need to write it. Either loop over your array to build a query, or use `array_keys()` and `array_values()` to extract what you need.

Comment: So I have to have two arrays and make a query like this, after use array_keys and array_value : INSERT INTO tablename ($arrayColumn) VALUES ($arrayValues) ?

Comment: @Nathan30 you mean insert into table ('res_id') values (104) like this ?

Comment: respective key with its value ?

Comment: @BunkerBoy More or less yes. I want only one request to insert all the values contains in my array. The values must match the respective key yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nathan30 try this :

```
 <?php
    $arr = array(
        "res_id" => 104,
        "subject" => "Test",
        "type_id" => 503,
        "format" => "pdf",
        "typist" => "fefe",
        "creation_date" => "2017-02-10 14:27:37.236711",
        "modification_date" => "2017-02-10 14:27:37.236711",
        "fulltext_result" => 1,
        "doc_date" => "2017-02-01 00:00:00",
        "docserver_id" => "FASTHD_MAN",
        "path" => "2017#02#0001##",
        "filename" =>" 0008.pdf",
        "fingerprint" => "",
        "filesize" => 84979,
        "status" => "VAL",
        "destination" => "DSG",
        "priority" => 2,
        "is_multi_docservers" => "N",
        "is_frozen" => "N",
        "tablename" => "res_letterbox",
        "initiator" => "COU",
        "dest_user" => "ddaull",
        "locker_user_id" => "fefefef",
        "locker_time" => "2017-02-13 15:52:25.624521",
        "confidentiality" => "N",
        "tnl_path" => "2017#02#0001##",
        "tnl_filename" => "0008.png",
    );
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
    $column = array();
    $values = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        $column[] = $key;
        $values[] = $value;
    }

    now query will be like:

    "insert into table values(".implode(',', $column).") values (".implode(',', $values).")";
```

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot. I just have to modify $values[] = $value; to     $values[] = "'" . $value . "'";
but your answer is what I needed